# Python 3 Turtle (line only renders halfway through canvas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, turtle-graphics

First off, I am abusing the turtle module. I have a small script that loops through all the images in a directory. Then using PIL it reads the RGB values of each pixel for the image it is "scanning". It changes the turtle to the color relative to that pixel and then moves the turtle to the location relative to the image (in the canvas). Effectively, I am recreating images using turtle.

I have more in mind for this later on, but I keep running into an issue where the all of the X pixels will render on the current Y axis until the next Y increment; then the previous row only renders halfway across the canvas correctly, with the second half being continuously one pixel color.

[image: Screenshot]

**Dependencies**

- PIL/PILLOW==4.0.0
- Canvasvg

**Note**
Any image should work as long as the image pallet is RGBA. If the image has an indexed color pallet, the script will crap out.

**Script**

```
# Imports
import os
import time
from PIL import Image
import turtle
import canvasvg

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.tracer(0)

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.shape("square")
pen.speed(0)

# Load Image
for image in os.listdir('image'):
    # Create Empty Level
    pixel = []
    # Open and process Image with PIL
    im = Image.open("image/" + image)
    width = im.size[0]
    height = im.size[1]
    wn.setup(width+50, height+50)
    pix = im.load()
    # Loop through the Y of the image
    for y in range(height):
        # Loop through the X of the image
        pen.pendown()
        for x in range(width):
            # Get color of pixel, set color of turtle
            color = pix[x,y]
            pen.color((color[0]/255, color[1]/255, color[2]/255))
            # Move turtle
            pen.goto(-(width/2) + x, (height/2) - y)
            # Debug Info
            print(x,y, pix[x,y])
        # Lift pen so there is not a streak across the window
        pen.penup()
        # Update the window
        wn.update()
        # Add delay so computer doesn't crap pants
        time.sleep(1)
    # Save canvas to SVG file
    canvasvg.saveall(image + ".svg",wn._canvas)
    # Reset window for next image.
    wn.reset()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem with your code:

```
pen.goto(-(width/2) + x, (height/2) - y)
```

This code creates retrace artifacts when it moves from the last pixel on one line to the first pixel on the next -- it is overdrawing half of the previous line (think of it as a slightly slanted line in the reverse direction).  Your `penup()` & `pendown()` don't fix this as the pen goes down before you get back to the beginning of the line.

I've rewritten your code below with some changes/optimizations -- see if this version gets around your issue:

```
# Imports
import os
import time
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from PIL import Image
import canvasvg

BORDER = 25

wn = Screen()
wn.colormode(255)
wn.tracer(0)

pen = Turtle("square", visible=False)
pen.speed("fastest")
pen.penup() # Lift pen so there is no streak across the window

# Load Image
for image in os.listdir('image'):
    # Open and process Image with PIL
    im = Image.open("image/" + image)
    pix = im.load()

    width, height = im.size
    wn.setup(width + BORDER*2, height + BORDER*2)

    # Loop through the Y of the image
    for y in range(height):

        pen.sety(height/2 - y)
        pen.pendown()

        # Loop through the X of the image
        for x in range(width):
            # Get color of pixel, set color of turtle
            pen.color(pix[x, y])
            # Move turtle
            pen.setx(x - width/2)
            # Debug Info
            # print(x, y, pix[x, y])

        pen.penup()
        # Update the window
        wn.update()
        # Add delay so computer doesn't crap pants
        time.sleep(1)

    # Save canvas to SVG file
    canvasvg.saveall(image + ".svg", wn.getcanvas())
    # Reset window for next image.
    wn.reset()

wn.mainloop()
```

Changes include: setting the color mode to match your color samples to avoid the divisions; moving the x and y of the pen separately to avoid some calculations in the inner loop; making the turtle invisible so you don't waste time drawing it.

Normally I'd use *stamping*, rather than *drawing*, for this sort of image work in turtle, but I see you need to do it via drawing for `canvasvg.saveall()` to work.

Also, this seems like an opportunity for using `setworldcoordinates()` to avoid doing coordinate math at the Python level but when I tried that, I got subtle image artifacts so I tossed it.

Comment: I appreciate the work. Seem's I got a bit antsy and just saw the artifacts in the canvas and assumed the output would be the same. Also appreciate your modifications. My end goal is to process the final image from reddit /r/place with each pixel being spaced 4 pixels apart and a separate turtle for each color.

Comment: @AaronHenderson, I think the artifact would be in the output file.  Even my solution, which fixes the screen image, isn't optimal output-wise as it draw an extra perfectly horizontal retrace line which really isn't needed in the SVG.  The problem is correctly drawing the x == 0 situation.  This is what stamping gets around, but that's not viable for your purpose.